# Сортировка матрицы. Разместить столбцы в порядке уменьшения сумм их элементов используя циклы и сортировку методом пузырька

Tags: python, матрицы, пузырьковая-сортировка

В задании указано, что нельзя пользоваться встроенными функциями, только сортировка методом пузырька. Посчитать сумму столбцов двумерной матрицы в отдельный список и уже по нему менять последовательность столбцов от столбца, сумма элементов которого больше, к столбцу с меньшей суммой элементов.  Я список с суммами отсортировала, но не понимаю как мне отсортировать столбцы. Использовать дополнительные функции нельзя. Вот мой код, все выполняет без ошибок, но не сортирует верно столбы по суммам их элементов

```
def sort(mm):
    z = [randint(0, 0) for _ in range(m)]
    for i in range(len(mm[0])):
        for j in range(len(mm)):
            z[i] += mm[j][i]
    swaped = True
    while swaped:
        swaped = False
        for el in range(len(z)-1):
            if z[el+1] > z[el]:
                z[el+1], z[el] = z[el], z[el+1]
                mm[j][el+1], mm[j][el] = mm[j+1][el], mm[j][el+1]

    for run in range(len(mm)-1):
        for i in range(len(mm)-1-run):
            for k in range(len(mm)):
                if k % 2 == 0:
                    if mm[i][k] < mm[i + 1][k]:
                        mm[i][k], mm[i + 1][k] = mm[i + 1][k], mm[i][k]
                else:
                    if mm[i][k] > mm[i+1][k]:
                        mm[i][k], mm[i+1][k] = mm[i+1][k], mm[i][k]
    print(*z)
    return mm
```

Comment: Какое-то у всех поветрие - писать без комментариев. Честно скажу, самому разбираться, где у вас что делается, и почему, где столбцы, где список с суммами - не очень интересно. Возможно, кто поопытнее вам поможет и без этого:-)

Comment: Да, исправлюсь, спасибо)

Answer (score 0):

Вот рабочее решение с комментариями для вашей задачи. Суть в том чтобы сортировать список и столбцы матрицы одновременно.

```
from random import *

# процедура для перестановки столбца col1 и col2 местами для матрицы m
def swap(m, col1, col2):
    rows = len(m)
    for i in range(rows):
        m[i][col1], m[i][col2] = m[i][col2], m[i][col1]

def sort(m):
    # получаем количество строк и столбцов
    rows = len(m)
    cols = len(m[0])

    # инициализируем список
    l = [0] * cols

    # считаем сумму
    for i in range (cols):
        for j in range(rows):
            l[i] += m[j][i]

    # сортируем пузырьком сразу и список и столбцы матрицы
    for i in range (cols):
        for j in range(cols - 1, i, -1):
            if (l[j - 1] < l[j]):
                l[j], l[j - 1] =  l[j - 1], l[j]
                swap(m, j, j - 1)
                
    return m

# матрица 4 строки 3 столбца          
arr = [[1, 2, 3],[7, 8, 9],[4, 5, 6],[7, 8, 9]]

# вывод матрицы
for i in arr:
    print(i)
            
arr = sort(arr)
# вывод пустой строки чтобы матрицы не сливались в консоли
print()
# вывод матрицы
for i in arr:
    print(i)
```

Comment: Спасибо, очень помогли!